# Adjust "sensitivity" of UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I was wondering if there is a way to modify the sensitivity of UIPanGestureRecognizer. What I'm doing is when the user pans up a bunch of red bars stack on top of each other like in the image here:

imgur.com/XHMBUdj

However, the only issue I'm facing is when I pan upward and downward, the bars come on the screen and disappear way too fast. It's strictly the pan gesture, because I implemented an index, and I can see the number go sky high (60's) for a simple swipe.